# Bratkartoffeln schälen

Tags: word-usage

Natürlich schält man zuerst die Kartoffeln und brät sie dann. Ich würde dennoch nie sagen:

> Ich schäle Kartoffeln für Bratkartoffeln.

oder

> Ich schäle Kartoffeln, um aus den geschälten Kartoffeln dann Bratkartoffeln zu machen.

Ich würde sagen:

> Ich schäle Bratkartoffeln.

Geht das?

---

*Beispiel:*

> ... wanderten sie zu ihrem Ferienhaus zurück. Dort schälte Leon die Bratkartoffeln, während sein Vater die Zwiebeln schnitt und Spiegeleier briet. Nach dem Essen ...

Comment: Das wäre für mich eine Stilblüte, die Stirnrunzeln bei mir hervorrufen würde, wenn ich das irgendwo lese. Sie liefern ja schon die Begründung: Bratkartoffeln zu schälen ergibt keinen Sinn. Genauso wenig wie die Pommes zu waschen oder gar das Steak zu schlachten.

Comment: "Ich schäle Kartoffeln für Bratkartoffeln." ist für mich ein völlig normaler Satz, den ich häufig sage (wobei ich allerdings lieber Pellkartoffeln für Bratkartoffeln verwende)

Answer (score 7):

<sub>(Ich mache meinen Kommentar mal zu einer Antwort.)</sub>

Ich empfinde den Satz

> Ich schäle die Bratkartoffeln.

als eine [Stilblüte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stilbl%C3%BCte), die, wenn ich das irgendwo lesen würde, Stirnrunzeln hervorrufen würde. Sie liefern ja schon die Begründung: Bratkartoffeln zu schälen ergibt keinen Sinn. Genauso wenig wie die Pommes zu waschen, die Senfgurken auszusäen oder das Steak zu schlachten.

Comment: Gegebenenfalls könnte man die *zukünftigen* Bratkartoffeln schälen.

Comment: So wie man zukünftige Steaks schlachtet?

Answer (score 7):

Ich finde das so witzig, dass ich zukünftig sicher öfter mal sagen werde, ich schäle Bratkartoffeln, auch wenn ich gar nicht vorhabe, die Kartoffeln zu braten.

Natürlich kann man sagen, dass die Kartoffeln, die da geschält werden, noch keine Bratkartoffeln sind. Genau betrachtet ist das aber Ansichtssache. Ab wann sind es denn Bratkartoffeln? Wenn sie fertig gebraten sind? Oder schon wenn sie halb fertig gebraten sind? Oder schon, wenn ich vorhabe, sie zu braten?

> Ich koche Kaffee.

Hier kocht man in Wahrheit ja auch nicht den Kaffee, sondern man kocht Wasser, um damit (als Endergebnis) Kaffee zuzubereiten.

> Ich schneide Speckwürfel.

Hier sind die Speckwürfel eindeutig das Endergebnis. Genau genommen macht es keinen Sinn, Speckwürfel zu schneiden.

Das Schälen der Kartoffeln ist ein Teil der Zubereitung des Gerichts Bratkartoffeln. Der in einer anderen Antwort gezogene Vergleich: *ein Steak schlachten* trifft nicht den Punkt. Es geht ja nicht darum, Bratkartoffeln zu ernten.

Kurzum: ja, es klingt witzig. Ob es aber tatsächlich eine Stilblüte ist (falscher inhaltlicher Bezug), darüber lässt sich streiten.

---

<sub>Fast hätte ich vergessen, die eigentliche Frage zu beantworten:</sub>

> Geht das?

Selbstverständlich geht das.

Wer das beispielsweise in einer Schülerarbeit liebevoll in roter Tinte als Fehler anstreicht, sollte m.E. besser bei der Sprachpolizei anfangen.

Als Diskussionsgrundlage zum Thema *bewusste Wortwahl*, *Genauigkeit in der Sprache* und *Stil* halte ich es dagegen für ein sehr gutes Beispiel.

Comment: Danke für den Kaffee und die Speckwürfel!

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort!

Comment: Schwierig, schwierig. Analogien und Sprache! Kaffee nennt man ja sowohl die Pflanze, das geröstete Zwischenprodukt als auch das Endprodukt. Zu Bratkartoffeln passt das nur bedingt: Wir ernten Kartoffeln und solange sie nicht gebraten sind würde ich sie nicht Bratkartoffeln nennen, außer es gäbe 2 Sorten, vorwiegend festkochende und mehligkochende vielleicht, eine bestimmt für Bratkartoffeln, eine für Kartoffelsalat und man wollte dann unterscheiden "Tante Inge schnappte sich die Schüssel mit den Bratkartoffeln...". Statt Spreckwürfel zu schneiden würde ich vorschlagen den Speck zu würfeln. :)

Comment: @userunknown Ja, Analogien sind immer schwierig. Es sind eben keine Digitalien. Die Frage *Geht das?* ist dagegen alles andere als schwierig zu 
 beantworten, solange niemand überzeugend darlegt, warum das nicht gehen 
sollte. Viel wichtiger als das Speckwürfeln finde ich übrigens, die Zwiebeln zu ringen! ;)

Comment: @userunknown *(...) würde ich vorschlagen den Speck zu würfeln* - was dann aber prompt die Frage nach der Augenzahl provoziert ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Ich schäle Bratkartoffeln.

Meiner Sprachintuition nach klingt das äußerst seltsam. Soweit mich mein Gedächtnis nicht trügt, ist mir zudem diese Formulierung im Gegensatz zu den Beispielen des `Kaffee kochens` bzw. `Speckwürfel schneidens` weder in gesprochener noch geschriebener Sprache jemals begegnet.

In einem Versuch, diese anekdotische Evidenz ein wenig zu objektivieren, kann man sich die Statistik einer Google-Suche anschauen:

'Kartoffeln schälen':     ~ 616.000 Treffer
'Kaffee kochen':          ~ 318.000 Treffer
'Bratkartoffeln schälen':        32 Treffer

Die in anderen Antworten oder Kommentaren herangezogenen Beispiele `Kaffee kochen` und `Speckwürfel schneiden` sind nicht völlig überzeugend: `Kaffee` kann das Kaffeepulver (bzw. die Bohne) bezeichnen, das beim Vorgang des Aufbrühens tatsächlich in gewissem Sinne gekocht wird, und `schneiden` kann auch im Sinne von `ausschneiden`/`zuschneiden` verwendet werden.

Generell gilt das Kompositionalitätsprinzip in der Semantik nicht zwingend: Die Bedeutung eines Kompositums oder einer Phrase läßt sich nicht verläßlich allein aus den Bedeutungen der Konstituenten ableiten.

Die gute Nachricht: Jeder Muttersprachler wird verstehen, was mit `Bratkartoffeln schälen` gemeint ist ...

Comment: Ich finde in diesem Post die Antwort einfach nicht. Erst erklärst du, dass die statistische Auswertung der Ausgabe *32 Treffer* eines Blackboxalgorithmus deine Aussage *noch nie gehört* zu objektivieren versucht. (Versuch gescheitert) Dann kommentierst du meine Antwort. Der Absatz *Generell gilt das Kompositionalitätsprinzip ... nicht zwingend ...* sagt genau ... was? Zu guter Letzt: ein Muttersprachler weiß, was gemeint ist. Na immerhin. Tut mir leid, aber das ist m.E. insgesamt nichts als pseudowissenschaftliche - um beim Thema zu bleiben - Soße.

Comment: @Olafant: Bevor du noch weiter suchst, lies dir einfach den ersten Absatz durch. Zur Erinnerung, die Frage lautete 'geht das?'. Ich bin mir nicht sicher, was du mit 'statistischer Auswertung der Ausgabe _32 Treffer_ eines Blackbox-Algorithmus' meinst, das ist sowohl Unsinn als auch nicht das, was in meinem Text steht. Vielleicht meinst du den Vergleich mit der um 4 Größenordungen höheren Treffermenge der Alternativformulierungen, dann solltest du das vielleicht auch so ausdrücken. Ach ja, und wenn du Kritik äußerst hilft es meistens, die kritisierte Aussage genau zu lesen ...

Comment: @Olafant ... In diesem Fall also das 'ein wenig' vor dem 'objektivieren' nicht unter den Tisch fallen zu lassen. 'Das Kompositionalitätsprinzip gilt nicht zwingend' bedeutet, daß das Kompositionalitätsprinzip nicht immer gilt, auch wenn es so scheinen mag - falls dir der Begriff selbst nichts sagt und meine Erklärung zu unverständlich ist, schlag das Lexikon auf, ggf. unter 'Frege-Prinzip'. Mit der Wertung 'pseudowissenschaftlich' unterstellst du mir wohl indirekt einen wissenschaftlichen Anspruch. Das ist zwar nett, paßt bei dieser Antwort aber nicht.

Comment: Wenn du nicht sicher bist, was ich meine, wie kannst du dann sicher sein, das es Unsinn ist? Google legt die Suchalgorithmen nicht offen. Damit lassen sich deren Ergebnisse nicht für *ein wenig* Objektivierung nutzen. Tut mir leid, dass ich die Erwähnung des Frege-Prinzips als wissenschaftlichen Anspruch missgedeutet habe. Was du damit sagen willst, ist mir immer noch schleierhaft.

Comment: @Olafant Stellst du dich jetzt absichtlich blöd ? Falls nicht, erkläre ichs aber gerne nochmal: Was du geschrieben hast und ich dann zitiert habe ist Unsinn. Daher konnte ich mir nicht sicher sein, was du meinst. Dein Argument zu Google ist genauso Unsinn. Das Argument ist die deutlich unterschiedliche Zahl der Suchergebnisse, die alle über Google ermittelt wurden. Aber ich wiederhole das Experiment gerne mit einer Suchmaschine, deren Algorithmus du als offen ansiehst (NB: auf welcher Hardware läuft die eigentlich - ist deren Spezifikation offen ?).

Comment: @Olafant Deine Mißdeutung muß dir nicht leid tun. Was der Hinweis auf das Frege-Prinzip verdeutlichen möchte: Die Bedeutung von '<Objekt> <Verb>' ergibt sich nach Frege vollständig aus der Bedeutung von <Verb>, <Objekt> und der (syntaktischen) Relation der beiden in der Phrase ('<Objekt> <Verb>'). Das läßt sich empirisch widerlegen ( 'Kaffee kochen', 'Speckwürfel schneiden', 'Krebs heilen' ).  Die ersten beiden Gegenbeispiele sind dabei die schwächeren, weil die Bedeutungen von <Objekt> bzw. <Verb> unscharf sind.

Comment: Du sprichst von anekdotischer Evidenz, (ein wenig!) Objektivierung, Statistik, Kompositionalitätsprinzip, das sich empirisch widerlegen lässt, hast aber keinen wissenschaftlichen Anspruch. Das ergibt so wenig Sinn wie die Behauptung eines Zusammenhangs zwischen Hardware und der Erhebungsmethode empirischer Daten. Da du offenbar die Relevanz des Algorithmus zur Datenerhebung nicht verstehst, muss dir natürlich auch meine Kritik als unsinnig erscheinen. Ich beende hier die Diskussion, weil sie offensichtlich nicht zur Klärung der eigentlichen Frage beitragen kann. Ist ja dein Post, nicht meiner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99957/discussion-between-collapsar-and-olafant).